# How to exclude NULL value in codeigniter and print in excel using get_where

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have developeded my web app using Codeigniter. I have some problems where to print the value from the database that excluded the null value. I'm trying to use 'where(value IS NOT NULL)' then the whole row in the database was excluded. but it not process the where.

> MODAL

```
public function get_distinct_fl_outgoing_feeder($obj_class, $bil, $source_file_id){

        switch ($bil) {

            case 'NEW':
                $this->db->from('sap_main, sap_outgoing_feeder');
                $this->db->join('sap_outgoing_feeder', 'sap_outgoing_feeder.sap_id = sap_main.id', 'right');
                $this->db->select('sap_main.id, sap_main.source_file_id, sap_main.category, sap_main.obj_label, sap_main.bil, sap_main.functional_location, sap_main.functional_location_desc, sap_main.fl_object_type, sap_main.cost_center, sap_main.business_area, sap_main.planner_group, sap_main.main_workcenter');
                $this->db->like('sap_main.bil', $bil);
                 $this->db->where('sap_outgoing_feeder.f10_fl IS NOT NULL OR sap_outgoing_feeder.f10_fl !=0');
                $result = $this->db->get_where('sap_main', array('sap_main.obj_class' => $obj_class, 'sap_main.source_file_id' => $source_file_id, 'sap_main.fl_status_flag' => 'O', 'sap_main.eq_status_flag' => 'O', 'sap_main.changed_fl_flag' => 'O'));
                   return $result->result_array();
                break;

            case 'EXISTING':
                $this->db->from('sap_main, sap_outgoing_feeder');
                $this->db->join('sap_outgoing_feeder', 'sap_outgoing_feeder.sap_id = sap_main.id', 'right');
                $this->db->select('sap_main.id, sap_main.source_file_id,sap_main.category, sap_main.obj_label, sap_main.bil, sap_main.functional_location, sap_main.functional_location_desc, sap_main.fl_object_type, sap_main.cost_center, sap_main.business_area, sap_main.planner_group, sap_main.main_workcenter');
                $this->db->not_like('bil', 'NEW');
                $this->db->where('sap_outgoing_feeder.f10_fl IS NOT NULL');
                $result = $this->db->get_where('sap_main', array('sap_main.obj_class' => $obj_class, 'sap_main.source_file_id' => $source_file_id, 'sap_main.fl_status_flag' => 'O', 'sap_main.eq_status_flag' => 'O', 'sap_main.changed_fl_flag' => 'O'));
                   return $result->result_array();
                break;

            default:
                $this->db->group_by('functional_location');
                $this->db->order_by('sap_main.id', 'ASC');
                // $this->db->where('f10_fl IS NOT NULL');
                $result = $this->db->get_where('sap_main, sap_outgoing_feeder', array('obj_class' => $obj_class, 'source_file_id' => $source_file_id, 'fl_status_flag' => 'O', 'eq_status_flag' => 'O', 'changed_fl_flag' => 'O'));
                return $result->result_array();
                break;

        }

    }
```

> CONTROLLER

```
function write_dlvdb01($data){

    $ci = get_instance();

    $source_file_id = $data['source_file_id'];

    $obj_label = $data['obj_label'];

    $header = $data['file_header'];

    $objects = $ci->sap_model->get_distinct_fl_outgoing_feeder('D_LVDB','ALL',$source_file_id);


    if($objects){

        $rowCount = 1;

        $counter = 0;

        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

        if($header){

            $label = ['Functional Location','Structure Indicator','Category','Functional Location Description','Object Type','Maintenance Plant','Company Code','Business Area','Cost Center','Maintenance Planning Plant','Planner Group','Main Workcenter','Eqp Allow'];

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(
                    $label,         // The data to set
                    NULL            // Array values with this value will not be set
                                        // Top left coordinate of the worksheet range where
                                        //    we want to set these values (default is A1)
                );

            $rowCount++;

        }

        foreach($objects as $object){

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $object['functional_location']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['functional_location_desc']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f1_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f1_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f2_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f2_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f3_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f3_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f4_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f4_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f5_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f5_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f6_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f6_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f7_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f7_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f8_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f8_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f9_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f9_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f10_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f10_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f11_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f11_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f12_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f12_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f13_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f13_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f14_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f14_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f15_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f15_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f16_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f16_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f17_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f17_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f18_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f18_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f19_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f19_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.++$rowCount, $object['f20_fl']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'TNBD');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $object['category']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $object['f20_description']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $object['fl_object_type']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$rowCount, '6001');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $object['business_area']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $object['cost_center']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$rowCount, '6000');
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $object['planner_group']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $object['main_workcenter']);
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$rowCount, '1');

            $rowCount++;

            $counter = $counter+ 4;

        }

        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setAutoSize(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setAutoSize(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setAutoSize(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setAutoSize(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')->setAutoSize(true);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('M')->setAutoSize(true);


        $file_directory = 'assets\\files\\downloads\\'.$ci->session->userdata('user_id').'\\sapFormat\\'.strtoupper($obj_label);

        if(!file_exists($file_directory)){

            mkdir($file_directory, 0777, true);

        }

        $filename = "01-D_LVDB-IL01-".$counter.".xls";

        $writer = new Xls($spreadsheet);

        $writer->save($file_directory.'\\'.$filename);

        $spreadsheet->disconnectWorksheets(); 

        unset($spreadsheet);

    }

}
```

> OUTPUT
>   [image: this is output product of excel]

I want to remove that white space.
Thanks for helping.

I found the solution where i put the condition on the controller. Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->db->where()` requires the second parameter to be passed even if you're passing `fieldname is not null` as the first parameter.

Since there's actually no second parameter to be passed, you need to use:

`$this->db->where('f10_fl IS NOT NULL', NULL);`

in query builder to exclude all rows where `f10_fl` has a `null` value in the table (or those which get nulled by an empty join)

Comment: when i use where, it not process because of get_where. should i change the rule get_where?

Comment: both statement should be able to coexist. You may try to put the `$this->db->get_where` statement before the `$this->db->where` one just to be sure. If that doesn't work, you may need to convert the `get_where` into multiple `where` statements

Comment: $this->db->from('sap_main');
    $this->db->join('sap_outgoing_feeder', 'sap_outgoing_feeder.sap_id = sap_main.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('f8_fl IS NOT NULL', NULL);
    $this->db->where('f8_description IS NOT NULL', NULL);
    $this->db->where('f9_fl IS NOT NULL', NULL);
    $this->db->where('f9_description IS NOT NULL', NULL); Im try this code, but still not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Active record code should be 
$this->db->where("f10_fl IS NOT NULL", NULL, FALSE);

Comment: Would you be better able to explain where this implementation should fit? This could better assist the asker in fixing his code.

Comment: this is the exact answer I provided above, but passing `FALSE` as the third statement is generally not recommended as it bypasses the protections (escaping, mostly) that query builder implements automatically